# Tag synonym [deploy] -> [deployment]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I would like to propose marking [deploy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy) as a synonym for [deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment).

Here's my rationale:

- the word `deploy` is the verb form of `deployment` and the two appear to be used similarly and interchangeably in prose
- the [tag description](https://serverfault.com/tags/deployment/info) for [deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment) can easily apply to [deploy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy) as well
- [deploy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy) does not have a [tag description](https://serverfault.com/tags/deploy/info), but if I were to write one, I am not sure how I would differentiate it from [deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment)
- usage stats:

  - [deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment): [652 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment)
  - [deploy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy): [56 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy)
  - both tags apply to [5 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy+deployment)

Comment: I would have considered this reasonable even without expounding on your rationale :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks pretty obvious to me.

The tags are now merged and synonymized: [deploy](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deploy) -> [deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/deployment)